# How to save timestamps in parquet files in C++ and load it in Python Pandas?

Tags: c++, pandas, parquet, pyarrow

I am using `Apache Arrow` in C++ to save a collection of time-series as a parquet file and use python to load the parquet file as a `Pandas` `Dataframe`. The process works for all types except the `Date64Type`. I am saving the epoch time in C++ and when loading it in pandas the time information is lost.

For example for boost posix time : `2018-04-01T20:11:17.112Z`, the epoch time (in `int64_t`) is `1522613477112000`, but when I saved to parquet file as (`Date64Type`) and load in pandas the result is `2018-04-01` and the time information is lost. What is the correct to save timestamps in parquet files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `arrow::TimestampType` instead. `Date32Type` and `Date64Type` only support day resolution; their internal representation is a bit different through (`int32_t` days since the UNIX epoch vs. `int64_t` milliseconds since the UNIX epoch)